# Import a function from __init__.py in Python

Tags: python, function, import, module, python-2.x

I have a module like below and I want to include a function from `__init__.py` in myfile.py

```
/mymodule
   /__init__.py
   /myfile.py
```

The init is

```
import mymodule.myfile

myInt = 5

def myFunction():
    print "hey"
```

and the myfile file

```
from mymodule import myFunction
from mymodule import myInt
...
```

So the myInt include works but not the myFunction one. Do you have an idea why?

Thanks

**EDIT**

The error message is `ImportError: cannot import name myFunction`

Comment: What does not works mean? Do you get an `ImportError`?

Comment: **Both** names should throw an exception; you have a circular import, don't do that. Move both `myInt` and `myFunction` to a separate nested module.

Comment: Can you provide runnable code that demonstrates the error when run? `myfile` isn't runnable, and I don't think it would produce the error you've posted if you removed the `...` (though I haven't tested it yet).

Comment: @user2357112: The code posted demonstrates the error.

Comment: I removed everything but the lines I have in my question and I have the same mistake. But in fact, I think @Martijn Pieters is right about the circular import. I need to move the function to a separate module or remove the include `import mymodule.myfile` from the `__init__.py` file.

Comment: I ran your code and it'll indeed throw an `ImportError: cannot import name myInt` exception for the code posted.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: It doesn't demonstrate the posted error. It produces an entirely different one.

Comment: @user2357112: It demonstrates an `ImportError`; just for `myInt`, not `myFunction`, as I suspected. If you swap the two import lines in `myfile.py` the exception is thrown the OP showed. I can live with that small difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a circular import:

- `myInt` and `myFunction` have not yet been assigned to when the `import mymodule.myfile` is run.
- `mymodule.myfile` then tries to import the names that are not yet assigned to from `mymodule`.

Your options are to move `myInt` and `myFunction` to a separate shared module:

```
mymodule/
    __init__.py
    myfile.py
    utilities.py
```

where `__init__.py` imports from both `mymodule.myfile` and `mymodule.utilities`, and `myfile.py` imports from `mymodule.utilities`.

Or you can import *just* the module in `myfile.py` and defer referencing the `myInt` and `myFunction` names until later (in a function call, for example):

```
import mymodule

def somefunction():
    mymodule.myFunction(mymodule.myInt)
```

By the time `somefunction()` is called all imports have completed and `mymodule.myFunction` and `mymodule.myInt` have been assigned to.